# Jupyter Notebook Can't Find Module installed with Conda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I installed a module through my computer's terminal using Conda (macOS), and the module runs when run out of terminal. However, this module also includes Python bindings I am trying to access in my Jupyter notebook, but it says "ModuleNotFound" every time. I have scoured the internet, but I feel I don't know enough about the subject to know exactly what question to ask to get the right answer. I figure it is a path problem, but I don't know where Jupyter looks for modules when running them, so I don't know what to alter the path to (or if it's even that).

Comment: Did you activate the relevant environment before launching jupyter notebook? I usually do this from an anaconda prompt with `conda activate your_env_name` and then `jupyter notebook`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you run `!which python` in a cell in your notebook and compare that to `output` of `what python` in your terminal. Same thing with `!conda info --all` in the notebook and `conda info --all` in the terminal. You can probably then add a symbolic link for the particular module in the path of the notebook environment. If you don't care about installing on your system yet again run in a cell in the notebook `%conda install <package name>`, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).